# Iterate through a DataTable columns using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

I want to iterate through `DataTable` columns using lambda expression. Currently I'm trying with `ForEach`. Below is the sample code.

```
foreach (DataColumn x in registeredpeople.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(tab + x.ColumnName);
    tab = "\t";
}
```

I want to achieve something like this, which we can do with the collection of list.

```
exampleCollection.ForEach(x =>
{
    sample.ID = x.Value,
    sample.Name = x.Text
});
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Why is a standard `foreach` no good?

Comment: @Magnus not because `foreach` is not good. I just want to maintain uniformity in my application, wherever possible I used lambda expressions instead of `foreach`. I feel lambda expression makes code clean.

Comment: You should read Eric Lippert from the C# compiler team's take on it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method of `List<T>`, so you have to convert that collection to a list. But is it really worth the effort?

```
registeredpeople.Columns  // returns a DataColumnCollection 
    .Cast<DataColumn>()   // needed because DataColumnCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<T> but just the non-generic IEnumerable(its old) 
    .ToList()             // needed because you want to use a method of List<T>, created a new List and fills it in a loop
    .ForEach(col => Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName));
```

Of course a `foreach` is more efficient and you don't have any benefit from `ForEach`.